# Date format within if statement in a while loop in php and mysql displays as 1st Jan, 1970

Tags: php, mysql

My code fetches date from the database. If the the date returned is NULL, i want it to be displayed as 00-00-0000 or Nothing instead of 1st Jan, 1970.
This is my code:

```
  <?php
  while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
  {
      $date_paid="";
      if ($date_paid == NULL) {
         $date_paid = $row['date_paid'];
      } else{
        $date_paid = date("jS M, Y", strtotime($row['date_paid']));
        } 
         echo "<tr><td>$date_paid</td></tr>";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: $date_paid="";   if ($date_paid == NULL) what is the idea here ?

Comment: If the result returned from the query is null, it displayed as 1st Jan, 1970. but my intention is to have it displayed as 00-00-0000

Comment: deprecated functions again!

Comment: My note was, that you are checking something which you set at the previous line.. which is pointless check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution...

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    if(empty($row['date_paid']) || $row['date_paid']==='0000-00-00'){
        $row['date_paid'] = '00-00-0000';
    } else {
        $row['date_paid'] = date("jS M, Y", strtotime($row['date_paid']));
    }
    echo $row['date_paid'];
}
```

Or inline..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $row['date_paid'] = empty($row['date_paid']) ? '00-00-0000' : date("jS M, Y", strtotime($row['date_paid']));
    echo $row['date_paid'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you solution but still the output is 1st Jan, 1970.

Comment: Do you have dates  < 1970 ? What value do you have inside this $row['date_paid'] at first place?

Comment: this are some of my values in the date_paid row  2015-11-07
2015-11-07
2015-11-06
2015-11-13
2015-11-13
2015-11-17
2015-11-20
2015-11-10
2015-11-05
2015-11-12
2015-11-09
2015-11-10
2015-11-20
2015-11-11
2015-11-16
2015-11-10
2015-11-05
2015-11-05
2015-11-24
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
0000-00-00

Comment: Ok so you don't have NULL's you have  0000 .. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks @svetlio for you support. my problem is now sorted.

Answer (score 1):

use MySQL `IF` or `DATE_FORMAT`

```
Select *,
IF(date_paid IS NULL, '00-00-0000', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%D %b,  %Y'))
date_paid From table
```

or other option change this `==` to this because `===` is compares type or value both

```
 if ($date_paid === NULL) {
```

Comment: I would prefer and i have tried the second option but still it is being displayed as 1st Jan, 1970

Comment: Select *,
IF(date_paid IS NULL, '00-00-0000', DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%D %b,  %Y'))
date_paid From table

Comment: try this query no need any php condition @BensonOThomas

Comment: What is the point to complicate the query with logic? Instead to process the result inside your code logic.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it gets:

```
$date_paid = $row['date_paid']
    ? date("jS M, Y", strtotime($row['date_paid']))
    : '00-00-0000';
```

Comment: still the output is 1st Jan, 1970 for values which are 0000-00-00

Comment: Question is: **If the the date returned is NULL, i want it to be displayed as 00-00-0000**. If you have different requirements, just tweak the conditionals to your liking.